# Base64 support for different API levels

Tags: android, base64, kotlin

In my Android app

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
        }
    ....
}
```

**Kotlin code**

```
val data = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    Base64.getDecoder().decode(str)
} else {
    Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT) // Unresolved reference: decode
}
```

Obviously, I got compilation error, when using Base64 variant prior to API 24.

But how can I support all the API levels and use Base64 as before 24, as after?

Comment: What is the import statement you are using?

Comment: import java.util.*

Comment: java.util.Base64 has decoder function, android.util.Base64 has decode function and exists from API 8

Answer (score 167):

Use **`android.util.Base64`** will resolve your problem its available from API 8

```
data = android.util.Base64.decode(str, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Example usage:

```
Log.i(TAG, "data: " + new String(data));
```

Comment: Right answer !!

Comment: you are the best!!!! You don't know how much time i search for the correct question!!!!!

Comment: in my case it returns null

Answer (score 14):

```
fun String.toBase64(): String {
    return String(
        android.util.Base64.encode(this.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    )
}


fun String.fromBase64(): String {
    return String(
        android.util.Base64.decode(this, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be using the **android.util.Base64** class. It is supported from API 8,

The Base64.getDecoder() function is part of java.util.Base64 and new in Java8.

Answer (score 4):

```
private String encodeFromImage() {
        String encode = null;
        if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            //encode = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            //String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,"Title",null);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                encode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(stream.toByteArray());
            } else {
                encode = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
        }
        return encode;
    }
```