# Load data with base64 encoding with loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, utf-8, base64, android-webview

I have an app which use `WebView` to show some local html to users. The app worked fine in last 2 years, but recently I'm getting too many reports that the app is showing some kind of error like this:

`"Web page not available The web page at data:text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8;base64, could not be loaded because: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE"`

obviously something changed in android or WebView, and it did, the [doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration) is saying:

> Stricter UTF-8 decoder    In Android 9, the UTF-8 decoder for Java
>   language is stricter and follows the Unicode standard.

so, I tried to load my data with base64 encoding to solve the problem.

```
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(resource.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
loadDataWithBaseURL(basePath, encodedHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64", null);
```

But this method just prints the raw base64 string. so I tried this:

`loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");`

and it shows the html without any problem.

BUT, I need to use `loadDataWithBaseURL` so I can post process the html, eg. loading css, font and so on.

so what's the difference between `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseURL` that cause one of them show the html and the other shows the raw base64 string?

Comment: I am encountering this also.  Have you learned any more about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) say (emphasis added)

> If the base URL uses the data scheme, this method is equivalent to calling loadData() and the historyUrl is ignored, and the data will be treated as part of a data: URL, including the requirement that the content be URL-encoded or base64 encoded. **If the base URL uses any other scheme**, then the data will be loaded into the WebView as a plain string (i.e. not part of a data URL) and any URL-encoded entities in the string **will not be decoded**.

which makes it sound like there's not a way to provide a base URL that's a website like `https://example.com`, unfortunately.

I was able to work around this by using the [html base tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) so relative URLs in links/images/etc. would still work.

```
String header = "<head> <base href='" + myBaseUrl + "'> </head>";
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString((header + resource).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
webview.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved without the header (Kotlin).

It's a bug or something with the base64.

```
webview
            .loadDataWithBaseURL(
                "http://baseurl.com/",
                data?.fromBase64(),
                "text/html; charset=utf-8",
                "UTF-8",
                null
            )
```

fromBase64() -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892843/1064316